# How do I upload files to my web server by passing the file path in the URL using Flask?

Tags: flask, web-development-server

I am able to upload files through forms using Flask but what I require is to be able to put the local file path in the URL and then flask can upload the file and process it. How do I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

well this is just not how a webserver works. If you want it to process the data locally stored on your computer you need to send it via a POST request.

Cheers, T